# Issue with hibernate mapping with 3 tables in springboot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to map three tables named log, action, properties with hibernate entity mapping and retrieve the data from these tables as logs via Json jackson using REST api GET. However only the data on two tables (log and action) are retrieved. It seems the third table is not mapped properly but there is no error trace to detect.

Here's the code for entity mapping of the first table log

```
package com.dafe.spring.applogger.entity;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="log")
public class UserLog {

    //define field

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="user_id")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name="session_id")
    private String sessionId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="userLog",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<Action>action;
    //define constructors

    public UserLog() {

    }

    public UserLog(String userId, String sessionId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
    }
    //define getters and setters


    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }


    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }


    public String getSessionId() {
        return sessionId;
    }


    public void setSessionId(String sessionId) {
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
    }

    public List<Action> getAction() {
        return action;
    }


    public void setAction(List<Action> action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Log [userId=" + userId + ", sessionId=" + sessionId + "]";
    }

}
```

Here's the entity mapping class for the second table.

```
package com.dafe.spring.applogger.entity;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;


@Entity
@Table(name="action")
public class Action {

    //declare & annotate your fields
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
    private int id;

@Column(name="time")
    private Timestamp time;

@Column(name="type")
    private String type;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="log_id")
private UserLog userLog;

@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy="action", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List <Properties> properties;


    //create and generate constructor
    public Action() {

    }

    public Action(Timestamp time, String type) {
        this.time = time;
        this.type = type;
    }

    //generate getters and setters

    public Timestamp getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(Timestamp time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public List<Properties> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(List<Properties> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Action [\n time=" + time + ",\n type=" + type  + "]";
    }

    //generate toString 



}
```

Here is the entity mapping for the last table which contains data that has not been successfully mapped or retrieved in json format.

```
package com.dafe.spring.applogger.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
@Table(name="properties")
public class Properties {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="locationX")
    private String locationX;

    @Column(name="locationY")
    private String locationY;

    @Column(name="viewedId")
    private String viewedId;

    @Column(name="pageFrom")
    private String pageFrom;

    @Column(name="pageTo")
    private String pageTo;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="action_id")
    private Action action;


    public Properties() {

    }

    public Properties(String locationX, String locationY, String viewedId, String pageFrom, String pageTo) {
        this.locationX = locationX;
        this.locationY = locationY;
        this.viewedId = viewedId;
        this.pageFrom = pageFrom;
        this.pageTo = pageTo;
    }


    public String getLocationX() {
        return locationX;
    }

    public void setLocationX(String locationX) {
        this.locationX = locationX;
    }

    public String getLocationY() {
        return locationX;
    }

    public void setLocationY(String locationY) {
        this.locationY = locationY;
    }

    public String getViewedId() {
        return viewedId;
    }

    public void setViewedId(String viewedId) {
        this.viewedId = viewedId;
    }

    public String getPageFrom() {
        return pageFrom;
    }

    public void setPageFrom(String pageFrom) {
        this.pageFrom = pageFrom;
    }

    public String getPageTo() {
        return pageTo;
    }

    public void setPageTo(String pageTo) {
        this.pageTo = pageTo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Properties [locationX=" + locationX +", locationY=" + locationY + ", viewedId=" + viewedId + ", pageFrom=" + pageFrom + ", pageTo="
                + pageTo + "]";
    }

}
```

Please help me figure this out. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I removed the @JsonIgnore from the Action.properties field and got the following error trace but still could not figure out the problem...:

```
<html><body><h1>Whitelabel Error Page</h1><p>This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.</p><div id='created'>Mon Mar 16 00:26:30 PDT 2020</div><div>There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).</div><div>Could not write JSON: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]-&gt;com.dafe.spring.applogger.entity.UserLog[&quot;action&quot;]-&gt;org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]-&gt;com.dafe.spring.applogger.entity.Action[&quot;properties&quot;])</div><div style='white-space:pre-wrap;'>org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]-&gt;com.dafe.spring.applogger.entity.UserLog[&quot;action&quot;]-&gt;org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]-&gt;com.dafe.spring.applogger.entity.Action[&quot;properties&quot;])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:296)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:181)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]-&gt;com.dafe.spring.applogger.entity.UserLog[&quot;action&quot;]-&gt;org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]-&gt;com.dafe.spring.applogger.entity.Action[&quot;properties&quot;])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:394)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:353)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:316)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:727)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:400)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1392)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:913)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:287)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:692)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2266)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:581)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:374)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:97)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column &#39;properties0_.page_from&#39; in &#39;field list&#39;
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
    ... 87 more
```

Please help me figure it out...

Comment: What happens if you remove `@JsonIgnore` from `Action.properties` ?

Comment: a bunch of errors show up......... : Could not write JSON: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]

Comment: The error says `Unknown column properties.page_from`. Are you sure you have your `@Column` names correctly mapped in your `Properties` class?

Comment: @vicpemir I have a column named pageFrom but i do not know why it says page_from. pageFrom is the name of the column both in my db and in entity class. I really need help

Answer (score 0):

In your action class you have the column as "id" and in the properties the column you match on in join column is "action_id"

Comment: yes, the action_id id the foreign key that joins with the properties table in mysql database. The id in the action class is the primary key that links to the foreign key action_id in properties class

Comment: Oh apologies, I thought the columns names needed to be the same regardless of whether they were FK or not

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix the error. I just added a line of code to m application.properties and voila... It worked!!!

Below is what I added.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update
```

Comment: You could just create additional database columns and tables by hands with the same effect. The reason was that you added something to the entities but didn't update the dtatabase.